# Direct complement of the subspace L in $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $$L=\{(z_1,...z_n) \in \mathbb C^n: Re_{z_{i}}-Im_{z_{i}}=0, i=1,...,n\}.$$
Write some base of the direct complement of the subspace L in $\mathbb C^n$ and find its dimension. 
I tried to find $dimL$ visualizing by $2\times n$ matrices. 
The dimension of a real vector space $\mathbb C^n$ is $2n$, is $dimL=n$?

Is $dimL$ equal to the dimension of a complex vector space $\mathbb C^n$?
Obviously, the complementary spaces must share the $\{0\}$.

Comment: Are we treating $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a real or complex vector space? Also, by 'direct' complement do you mean the complementary subspace? i.e. the subspace $W \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ for which $\mathbb{C}^n=L \oplus W$?

Comment: It is a real vector space, sorry for that, I tried to relate the dimension of the complex one with the subspace L.

Comment: And by the direct complement, I mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Re(z_j)-Im(z_j)=0$ is equivalent to $Re(z_j)=Im(z_j)$. Thus for any $v=(z_1,...,z_n)^\top \in L$ $z_j$ is of the form $z_j=a_j+a_ji=a_j(1+i)$ for some $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$. That is, any $v \in L$ can be written as,
$$v=(a_1(1+i),...,a_n(1+i))^\top=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \ell_j,$$
where $\ell_j$ is the vector with $1+i$ in the $j^{th}$ coordinate and $0$ in every other coordinate. It's hopefully easy to see that $\{\ell_1,...\ell_n\}$ are linearly independent and thus we have shown $L \subset span\{\ell_1,...\ell_n\}.$ The reverse inclusion follows since each $\ell_j \in L$. Thus $\dim L=n$. Thus the complement subspace then has dimension $n$ as well. Can you find the basis? Does this help?

Comment: If I understood, $\{\ell_1,...\ell_n\}$  is the basis of the L, which I kind of intuitively considered, so can the vectors of the form $a_j(1+2i)$ generate the complementary space? Thank you for the notation.

Comment: I believe so. Intuitively, in each coordinate you want a complex number that is linearly independent with $1+i$. Other examples would be $1-i$, $10-i$, etc.